# AWS SQL Server to MySQL data migration

Tags: mysql, sql-server, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to migrate an Amazon Web Service SQL 2008 RDS to an AWS MySQL RDS to lower monthly costs.  I've migrated one complete database schema.  Two of the tables (in the SQL db) have around 40000 rows of data.  During my original migration (from SQL 2003) I migrated the schema and used the 'bcp utility' to move the larger tables of data.  This worked great with no indexing errors.  Example:

```
bcp test.dbo.letters out C:\backup\letters.txt -n -E -S 99.100.100.100 -U sa -P password -b 10000 

bcp test.dbo.letters in C:\backup\letters.txt -n -E -S myamazon-mssql-endpoint.com -U username -P password -b 10000
```

So my question is, can I use the 'bcp utility' for bulk export of SQL data and use some MySQL CLI bulk import tool to migrate the data into my new MySQL tables?

PS - I've tried the MySQL Workbench Migration tool with no luck.  Also, I have no triggers or stored procedures.

Comment: I guess I don't understand the question.  You said you aeems you have already accomplished what your question is asking about.

Comment: I went from SQL 2003 to SQL 2008 using the bcp utility.  Now I need to go from SQL 2008 to MySQL.  I think the 'bcp utility' only supports native SQL data types.  So, I think I need a MySQL type 'bcp utility' to import the data into MySQL.  However, I'm not sure what that would be or if it's compatible with the 'bcp utility' export.

Comment: You say you tried the MySQL Workbench Migration tool "with no luck."  What does that mean, in a bit more detail?

Comment: There's simply too much data to migrate using MySQL workbench migration tool (or any GUI toooking for a CLIl for that matter).  I'm looking for a CLI tool and solution.